# The set of points is the intersection of union of certain sets

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be the set of all points such that $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ as $n\to \infty$.

Let $x_0\in X$ then $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ $\exists k$ such that $\forall j\geq k$ we have $|f_j(x_0)-f(x_0)|<\frac{1}{n}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ $\exists k$ such that $x_0\in\{x:|f_j(x)-f(x)|<\frac{1}{n}, \forall j\geq k\}=:E_{n,k}$ $\Rightarrow$  $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ $x_0\in \bigcup\limits_{k}E_{n,k}$ $\Rightarrow$  $x_0\in \bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{k}E_{n,k}$.

In other words, $X=\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{k}E_{n,k}$.

Am I right?

**EDIT:** However, in the book of Stein the author does not take intersection over $n$. This is confusing. Could anyone explain me this moment please?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, Thanks for answer! I have edited my question. Could you take a look, please?

Comment: Note that in your argument $X \subset \cup_k E_{n,k}$. Hence $X=\cup_k (E_{n,k}\cap X)$. This is true for each $n$ and this is the statement in that proof of Egorofff's Theorem.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, Since $E_{n,k}\subset X$ then $E_{n,k}\cap X=E_{n,k}$ so $X=\cup_{k} E_{n,k}$, right?

Comment: Yes, right again.